# How to select first 2 rows using group's

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, greatest-n-per-group

I have:

**Table1**

```
ID  date       amt
-------------------    
001 21/01/2012 1200
001 25/02/2012 1400
001 24/03/2012 1500
001 21/04/2012 1000
002 21/03/2012 1200
002 01/01/2012 0500
002 08/09/2012 1000
.....
```

I want to select the first two rows from each group of `ID` ordered by `date` DESC from `Table1`.

Query looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP 2 DATE, ID, AMT FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY ID, AMT --(NOT WORKING)
```

Expected output:

```
ID  date       amt
-------------------
001 21/01/2012 1200
001 25/02/2012 1400
002 21/03/2012 1200
002 01/01/2012 0500

.....
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can take advantage of using `Common table Expression` and `Window Function`

```
WITH recordList
AS
(
    SELECT  ID, DATE, Amt,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE ASC) rn
    FROM    tableName
)
SELECT  ID, DATE, Amt
FROM    recordList
WHERE   rn <= 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d26ba/1)

based on your desired result above, you are ordering the date by `ASCENDING`.

Ok, You can either use `DENSER_RANK()` or `ROW_NUMBER()` but in my answer, I've used `DENSE_RANK()` because I'm thinking of the duplicates. Anyway, it's the choice of the OP to use `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of `DENSE_RANK()`.

- [TSQL Ranking Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Comment: Do you have any special reasons to use row_number() instead of dense_rank()?

Comment: @ntalbs the reason why i'm using `DENSE_RANK()` is because i'm thinking of duplicate rows.